# Power BI Slicers formatting incorrectly

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I'm having issues with slicers displaying differently in Power BI server across multiple users.

This is what the slicers look like for me:

[image]

For another user they are appearing like this:

[image]

Is there a setting others need to adjust to get the proper view?

Comment: Is there any difference in browsers between the users?

Comment: We are both using Google Chrome. Unsure if there is a version difference. She's based in Germany while I'm based in the US - not sure if that has anything to do with it either. We're both using PCs

Answer (score 0):

Your first user has the search feature on the visuals turned off, the second has them turned on. Toggle them using the ellipses menu.

[image]

Comment: The user doesn't have editing access so I don't think they'd be able to change it in PBI server. They are only a viewer.

Comment: It is not an edit option. It's available on the visuals when viewing.